# How to implement the "Square root of Swap gate" on the IBM Q (composer)?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, ibm-q-experience

I would like to simulate a quantum algorithm where one of the steps is ["Square root of Swap gate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Square_root_of_Swap_gate_(%E2%88%9AS)) between 2 qubits.

How can I implement this step using the [IBM composer](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/editor)?

Comment: Maybe it can be useful to use simple [swap gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Swap_(S)_gate) as a "brick" to construct square root of swap gate. You can simulate on IBM Q in this way: cx q[1],q[0];
h q[0];
h q[1];
cx q[1],q[0];
h q[0];
h q[1];
cx q[1],q[0];

Comment: @JanVdA The square root is not unique.  In fact, there should be 2^4=16 possible roots.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: Anyone would do for me. No preference for a particular one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is [a SQRT(SWAP) construction](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA2%22%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%5D%7D) which only requires CNOTs in one direction, Hadamards, S gates ($Z^{\frac{1}{2}}$), S dagger gates ($Z^{-\frac{1}{2}}$), T gates ($Z^{\frac{1}{4}}$) and T dagger gates ($Z^{-\frac{1}{4}}$):

[image]

You should be able to encode it directly into the composer.

Comment: How does one obtain this from first principles?

Comment: @user1271772 Which are the "first principles"?

Comment: I don't know how to implement $Z^{1/2}$ and $Z^{-1/2}$ using the IBM composer.

Comment: @user1271772 I started with the CNOT-NOTC-CNOT SWAP circuit, replaced the middle CNOT with a C-sqrt(not) to make the whole thing a sqrt(SWAP), decomposed the C-srt(not) into S+CNOT gates, moved some gates around until I managed to cancel one of the CNOTs, then used Hadamards to flip the direction of any CNOT pointing the wrong way.

Comment: @JanVdA $Z^{1/2}$ is $S$, and $Z^{-1/2}$ is $S^\dagger$ (look at the blue gates in the composer).

Comment: I simulated the above on IBM composer and I didn't get the expected  outcome.  So first I applied X-gate to the qubit 0 - so I get |01>, when I then apply the above SQRT(SWAP) construction it always returned  10 as output while I would expect 10 in 50% and 01 in the other 50% of the cases.

Comment: @JanVdA could you link a picture of your circuit?

Comment: Here a picture of my circuit https://imgur.com/Rd8gm4K

Comment: @JanVdA Bah, I got some angles doubled by accident and somehow didn't notice. I updated the answer with the correct circuit.

Comment: excellent: I just tested it and it gave in about 50% of the cases 01 and in the other 50% cases 10 when 10 is provided as input.

Comment: @JanVdA That doesn't mean it's a square root of swap.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch  I agree that my test is not a prove that the above circuit implements a square root of swap.  If it is not the case please raise so.

Comment: @JanVdA Why don't you test it yourself?  Eeach gate is a 4x4 matrix. Multiply them and check what you get.

Comment: Craig, see comment @NorbertSchuch : is there a prove that above circuit indeed implements the SQRT(SWAP) gate.  I guess you have used the algassert.com site for this but I have no experience with that.  I also notice that the link [a SQRT(SWAP) construction] in the answer refers to a diagram that contains other gates besides the gates that are shown in the diagram pasted in the answer.

Comment: @JanVdA Dude: Write down the matrices for each gate and multiply them.  If you don't know how to do that, you should start by learning that first.  Otherwise, there is no way you will succeed developing quantum algorithms.

Comment: Multiplying matrices is obviously a good skill to have, but I think it is valid to want to get some experience in first. I'd suggest to @JanVdA that you prepare Bell states and test your sqrt(swap) gates on them. If they work, they should have no effect (though this is again not a full proof).

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is a rotation on the subspace spanned by $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ which rotates it by $\sqrt{X}$.  To this end, you can first do a CNOT, which maps this subspace to $\{|01\rangle,|11\rangle\}$.  Now you need to do the $\sqrt{X}$ rotation on the first qubit, conditioned on the second qubit being one.  Implementing controlled-$U$ gates using CNOTs is a standard construction, which can be found in a range of places, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016. Depending how you do this step, you might have to fix the "global" phase of the 1st qubit (given the 2nd is $|1\rangle$).  Finally, you need to undo the CNOT.

Comment: It is not clear to me 1) how you do a $\sqrt{X}$ in  composer. 2) how to undo a CNOT in composer 3) you mention controlled-U gates but it is not clear where they should be used in the algorithm.
I think that a step wise description of the algorithm would be helpful for implementing this on the IBM composer.

Comment: @JanVdA I'm afraid you'll have to do some work yourself to familiarize yourself with quantum circuits and their manipulations.  Otherwise, what are you going to do once you know the circuit for the sqrt-SWAP?

Comment: FYI: I have used the above sqrt-SWAP description to test the solution suggested for https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-to-create-a-quantum-algorithm-that-produces-2-n-bit-sequences-with-equal-num on the IBM composer.

Comment: @JanVdA Which one? The accepted one? That one only talks about a controlled-SWAP.  (For that: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.53.2855)

Comment: Sorry I am referring to the accepted solution for question:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301733/how-to-create-a-quantum-algorithm-that-produces-2-n-bit-sequences-with-equal-num

Answer (score 0):

Every 2-qubit gate has a "Paulinomial decomposition" which means it can be written as a polynomial of Pauli matrices.

For the gate you want:

$
\sqrt{ \mbox{SWAP} } = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1  &  0  &  0  &  0  \\
0  &  \frac{1}{{2}} (1+i)  &  \frac{1}{{2}} (1-i)  &  0  \\
0  &  \frac{1}{{2}} (1-i)  &  \frac{1}{{2}} (1+i)  &  0  \\
0  &  0  &  0  &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1-i}{4}\left(X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2+Z_1Z_2\right) +\frac{3+i}{2}I,
$

where $X_i$ is an $X$ gate applied to the $i^\textrm{th}$ qubit.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer -  I need to study a bit to figure out how I can translate this to the IBM Composer.

Comment: @JanVdA What's wrong? Can't you drag and drop the X,Y, and Z gates into the circuit? You may wish to ask a separate question about how to multiply a gate by a constant.

Comment: I can drag and drop X, Y, Z gates but I don't know how to do the multiplications (e.g. $X_1X_2$), the additions (e.g. $X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2$), the multiplication by a constant, I even don't know what you mean by $I$.  I guess I must sound like a complete idiot.

Comment: $X_1X_2$ means you're applying $X$ to qubit 1 and $X$ to qubit 2. However, as I mention in the previous comment, I think you should ask a separate question about how to multiply by a constant.

Comment: See also Eq. 8 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10478.pdf, and the circuit diagrams in the supplementary material. Eq. 8 of the paper is exactly like what I gave you, except with only $Z$ gates. It's still a "Paulinomial" but with only $Z$ gates, and it is implemented in the IBM composer in that paper.

Comment: I admit I am still lost in the dark or at least I am having exactly the same questions.  Note that you can also easily check this on [IBM Composer](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/editor)

Comment: @user1271772 You can't do additions of gates in quantum circuits.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: They did here: arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10478.pdf

Comment: @user1271772 Their Eq. 8 you refer to above is a Hamiltonian, not a unitary.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I see.