# How to implement a Square root of Swap gate that swaps 2n-qubits on the IBM Q (composer)?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I am looking for an implementation using the quantum gates provided by the [IBM composer](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/editor) of the following quantum function:

- input $2n$ qubits
- output $2n$ qubits wherein $50\%$ of the cases the state of the $2$ sets of $n$ qubits are swapped and in the other $50\%$ of the cases the state of the $2n$ qubits remain unchanged.  With swapped I mean that qubit $q[i]$ will get the state of qubit $q[n+i]$ and qubit $q[n+i]$ will get the state of $q[i]$.  Note also that all the qubits must be swapped or not.

E.g. $n=3$: If input $|000111\rangle$ then output in 50% of the cases is  $|000111\rangle$ and in the other 50% of the cases is  $|111000\rangle$

We have already a solution when $n=1$ in the following StackOverflow question:

- [How to implement the "Square root of Swap gate" on the IBM Q (composer)?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-implement-the-square-root-of-swap-gate-on-the-ibm-q-composer)

but how can we do that when $n>1$?

Comment: I wonder if we can use a classical coin-flipper, and add an "if" statement in the [QASM](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/qasm) editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general trick for smoothing a big discrete operation into a continuous operation is to apply the phase estimation algorithm, then apply a phase gradient to the phase register, then uncompute the phase estimation. For example, see [this blog post on computing the fractional fourier transform](http://algassert.com/post/1710).

Because the swap operation has exactly two eigenvalues (+1 and -1), the phase estimation is extremely simple. It only requires a single phase estimation qubit. The [resulting circuit](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Density3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Density3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5Et%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Density3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Density3%22%5D%5D%7D) looks like this:

[image: Big sqrt swap]

Note that the top qubit should start and end in the 0 state. You can continuously vary how much swappery there is by varying the angle of the Z rotation in the middle.

Comment: thanks for the circuit.  If you don't care about the output state of the top qubit: would the first part of the circuit (up to and not including the 2nd H gate) not already implement the square root of swap gate that swaps 2x3 qubits ?

Comment: @JanVdA No, that's just the first phase estimation. You'll just have a qubit telling you which eigenspace of the swap operation the other qubits are in. You need to use it and get rid of it for the circuit to work.