# Expressing "Square root of Swap" gate in terms of CNOT

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

**How could a $\sqrt{SWAP}$ circuit be expressed in terms of CNOT gates & single qubit rotations?**

[image: CNOT & SQRT of SWAP]

- CNOT & $\sqrt{SWAP}$ Gates

> Any quantum circuit can be simulated to an arbitrary degree of accuracy using a combination of CNOT gates and single qubit rotations.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate

> Both CNOT and $\sqrt{SWAP}$ are universal two-qubit gates and can be transformed into each other.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Universal_quantum_gates

**Edit**

> The questions are not identical, and are likely to attract different audiences. -DaftWullie

Can the difference be regarded as applied vs theoretic?

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-implement-the-square-root-of-swap-gate-on-the-ibm-q-composer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement the "Square root of Swap gate" on the IBM Q (composer)?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-implement-the-square-root-of-swap-gate-on-the-ibm-q-composer)

Comment: @Blue I think that while the answers are essentially the same, the questions are not identical, and are likely to attract different audiences.

Comment: May have been better to post edit as comment? Also, to be clear, the circuit that @DaftWullie posted at the end is what I was after (which I did not see in the other post).

Comment: @Blue It is indeed a candidate for closure. But given there are slight differences and willing answerers, I'll let it live.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by @Nelimee, this question is essentially answered in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2228/1837), even if that question seems more specific. However, for the sake of completeness... (Note that I make no claims about minimality of construction with respect to, for example, number of controlled-not gates.)

Let's start with a unitary matrix for the square root of SWAP:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Note that if we pre- and post-multiply by a controlled NOT, controlled off qubit 2, this transforms into the form of a controlled-$U$ gate:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
There are standard constructions for this controlled-$U$ gate. So, overall, we have a circuit that looks like
[image]
where $ABC=\mathbb{I}$ and $AXBXC=e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{X}$. Again, there are standard routes towards finding $A$, $B$ and $C$. For instance, we can define $R_Y(\theta)$ to be a rotation about the $Y$ axis by an angle $\theta$, i.e. $R_Y(\theta)=e^{i\theta Y}$ (there may be a factor of $\frac12$ here compared to some definitions). Then, if
$$
A=R_Y(\theta)R_Z(\phi)\qquad B=R_Z(-2\phi)\qquad C=R_Z(\phi)R_Y(-\theta),
$$
then it's easy to verify that $ABC=\mathbb{I}$. Furthermore, $AXBXC=R_Y(\theta)R_Z(4\phi)R_Y(-\theta)$ since $XR_Z(\phi)X=R_Z(-\phi)$. You can think of this as $R_Z(4\phi)$ specifying the eigenvalues that we want, and the $R_Y(\theta)$ is changing the basis from the computational basis into something else. In the present case, we have $\theta=\pi/2$ and $4\phi=\pi/4$.

The one little thing that we haven't got right yet is a phase factor. Our $AXBXC$ is creating the correct rotation up to an overall phase of $e^{i\pi/4}$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The trick to get this right is to apply an $R_Z(\pi/8)$ on the first qubit and remove a global phase of $e^{i\pi/8}$. Thus, we have
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think that you want answers to explicitly use full cnots, rather than partial versions. But since you already have an answer for that, I'll contribute a different perspective.

A $\mathrm{SWAP}$ can be thought of as a cnot that has been conjugated by oppositely oriented cnots.

$$\mathrm{SWAP} = {\rm cx}(k,j) \,\, {\rm cx}(j,k) \,\, {\rm cx}(k,j) $$

To make a $\sqrt{\mathrm{SWAP}}$, we can instead use a square root of cnot conjugated by oppositely oriented cnots.

$$ \sqrt{\mathrm{SWAP}} = {\rm cx}(k,j) \,\, \sqrt{{\rm cx}(j,k)} \,\, {\rm cx}(k,j) $$

To verify that this is indeed a $\sqrt{\mathrm{SWAP}}$, you can simply square it and verify that it ends up in the way we expect (using the fact that cnots square to identity).

Comment: Awesome! Your $\mathrm{SWAP}$ approach makes me think of [an unanswered question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2352/quantum-xor-linked-list-construction)..