# How to implement $\sqrt{iSWAP}$ in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, gate-synthesis

I want to implement the $\sqrt{iSWAP}$ operator using simple operations in Qiskit such as it is done for the $iSWAP$ [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.iSwapGate.html)  or $\sqrt{SWAP}$ gate [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-implement-the-square-root-of-swap-gate-on-the-ibm-q-composer). How can I do this? If possible I would like to know what 'methods' do people use to find such decomposition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the

$$\sqrt{iSWAP} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & i/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & i/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

then we can use the `decompose` method in qiskit to get the set of elementary gates that would be implement on IBM hardware, which comes out to be:

[image]

You can use [quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk) to do the something similar I believe. Now, recently IBM changes its native set of gates to $\{ CZ, ID, RZ, SX, X \}$. So to see how this being implement on the hardware you can use the [`transpilation`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html) method. Which will transpile the above circuit to the following circuit on 'ibmq_athens':

[image]

---

If you wish to do the decomposition within qiskit, you can use the following script:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
import numpy as np
sqrt2 = np.sqrt(2)
controls = QuantumRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(controls)
Matrix = Operator( [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1/sqrt2, 1j/sqrt2, 0],
    [0, 1j/sqrt2, 1/sqrt2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1] ])
circuit.unitary(Matrix, [0,1])
decomp = QuantumCircuit.decompose(circuit) 
print(decomp)
```

And the transpilation process can be done as:

```
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
Circuit_Transpile = transpile(decomp, provider.get_backend('ibmq_athens') , optimization_level=3)
print(Circuit_Transpile)
```

Comment: Thank you! How would a basic code look like fo rusing the decompose method? do I need to construct the circuit with the corresponding gate I want to decompose?

Comment: I added the script of code that shows you how to do the decomposition in Qiskit.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a $\sqrt{iSWAP}$ gate like this:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import iSwapGate
sqrt_iSWAP = iSwapGate().power(1/2)
```

The matrix representation is the following:

```
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(sqrt_iSWAP.to_matrix())
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i & 0  \\
 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

You can add that gate to a circuit as follow:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.append(sqrt_iSWAP, [0, 1])

circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Following, transpiled to the IBMQ Athena backend:

```
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
from qiskit import IBMQ

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
transpiled = transpile(circuit, provider.get_backend('ibmq_athens') , optimization_level=3)
transpiled.draw('mpl', idle_wires=False)
```

[image]